# Install MySQL Timezone Support (MAMP PRO 3.0.7.3)

Tags: php, mysql, macos, mamp, mamp-pro

I'm trying to figure out how to fill the timezone tables in MySQL.  I'm new to developing on a Mac.  This is my first time trying to set this up and I'm finding it difficult to find instuctions.  I've seen posts where they say the `mysql_tzinfo_to_sql` file should be located here `/usr/share/lib/zoneinfo` as it is supposed to come with Macs.  Well it didn't with mine.  I have a brand new MacBook Pro.  Spotlight says the file is located in `applications/MAMP/Library/bin` so I opened the terminal, went to that directory and typed this in...

```
Gordons-MacBook-Pro:bin gordonfrobenius$ ./mysql_tzinfo_to_sql | ./mysql -p -u root mysql
Usage:
 ./mysql_tzinfo_to_sql timezonedir
 ./mysql_tzinfo_to_sql timezonefile timezonename
 ./mysql_tzinfo_to_sql --leap timezonefile
Enter password:
```

I enter the password and nothing happens.  The timezone tables are still empty.  Please help.

- MAMP 3.0.7.3
- MacBook Pro OS X Yosemite v 10.10.2
- PHP 5.6.2
- MySQL innodb_version 5.5.38

**UPDATE:** I just tried running this as other posts suggested, got a little further but not quite there, trying to figure out what this error means now...

```
Gordons-MacBook-Pro:bin gordonfrobenius$ ./mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | ./mysql -p -u root mysql
Enter password: Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/+VERSION' as time zone. Skipping it.
```

Following this post now, might be on the right path... http://www.larryullman.com/forums/index.php?/topic/2629-ch-6-pg-190-step-by-step-instructions-for-how-to-load-time-zone-table-info/

Comment: Try restarting the mysql daemon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These instructions solved the problem: http://www.larryullman.com/forums/index.php?/topic/2629-ch-6-pg-190-step-by-step-instructions-for-how-to-load-time-zone-table-info/

I found that it is easier to move that +VERSION file out of `usr/share/zoneinfo` by navigating to that location in terminal, then typing `open .`.  That causes a finder to open in that location, then you can drag it to desktop (you will have to authenticate).  Then when done loading the timezone data drag it back in.